# Behave / python3: Test undefined even if the step function is present

Tags: python, python-3.x, gherkin, python-behave

I have started using behave to define behaviour-driven tests on Python3.
The first tests went fine, but now I am incurring in a most puzzling error.

I have define this Gherkin file `sra-to-isatab-batch-conversion.feature`:

```
Feature: SRA to ISA-tab Batch conversion
# perform a batch conversion of a set of SRA datasets, retrieved from the European Nucleotide Archive
# to ISA-tab

Scenario: Batch conversion form a list of SRA accession numbers
 Given An access number "ERA000084"
 And nothing else
 When the SRA to ISA tab conversion is invoked
 Then it should return a ZIP file object
 And the ZIP file should contain as many directories as the element in the list
```

Then I define the following step methods in a file `steps/sra-to-isatab-batch-conversion.py`

```
from behave import *

use_step_matcher("parse")


@given('An access number "{access_number}"')
def step_impl(context, access_number):
    context.access_number = access_number
    print(context.access_number)

@step("nothing else")
def step_impl(context):
    print("Nothing else") 


@when("the SRA to ISA tab conversion is invoked")
def step_impl(context):
 pass


@then("it should return a ZIP file object")
def step_impl(context):
    pass


@step("the ZIP file should contain as many directories as the element in the list")
def step_impl(context):
    pass
```

If I then run `behave sra-to-isatab-conversion.feature` the step function related to the `when` step appears to be missing:

```
Feature: SRA to ISA-tab Batch conversion # sra-to-isatab-batch-conversion.feature:2

Scenario: Batch conversion form a list of SRA accession numbers                  # sra-to-isatab-batch-conversion.feature:6
Given An access number "ERA000084"                                             # steps/sra-to-isatab-batch-conversion.py:6 0.000s
And nothing else                                                               # steps/sra-to-isatab-batch-conversion.py:40 0.000s
When the SRA to ISA tab conversion is invoked                                  # None
Then it should return a ZIP file object                                        # None
And the ZIP file should contain as many directories as the element in the list # None

/Users/massi/Projects/oerc/isa-api/features/test_outputs

Failing scenarios:
  sra-to-isatab-batch-conversion.feature:6  Batch conversion form a list of SRA accession numbers

0 features passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
0 scenarios passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
2 steps passed, 0 failed, 2 skipped, 1 undefined
Took 0m0.001s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

@when(u'the SRA to ISA tab conversion is invoked')
def step_impl(context):
    raise NotImplementedError(u'STEP: When the SRA to ISA tab conversion is invoked')`
```

I have tried to redefine the step description change the number of given statements,I have even rewritten the files, but I always get this same errors. Even if I copy the statement suggested in the error message I still get the very same error.

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong?
I am using
Python 3.4
Behave 1.2.5
PyCharm 5.0.4 (notice that PyCharm BDD tools recognise the matching between statements in the Gherkin file and the step functions)

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, its currently working just fine for me with your exact implementation as you pasted above. Could be an environment issue or and installation problem. Can you try reinstalling behave? also are you running it from your terminal or from pycharm?

PS: not an issue, but you don't need to specify the use_step_matcher() method if you are using parse; since its the default [step_matcher](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/api.html?highlight=parse#step-parameters)

Also (making sure not a pasting human error from you): your @when step method has an indentation issue on the "pass" statement. Is it really like that in your code or just a format issue here in the forum?

Comment: Thank you for the anwer. No, the indentation error is not in my code, I just haven,t understood yet how to import code correctly to StackOverflow! So it seems to be an environment issue. I'll do as you suggested and see how it goes